# Regex matches only last occurence instead of all occurrences

Tags: regex

I have this pattern

```
.*;\/wp-content\/uploads\/(.*)\.
```

and this in string format

```
<div class="js-aem-gallery" data-images="{&#34;omniture&#34;:{&#34;type&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;hasImpression&#34;:false},&#34;slides&#34;:[{&#34;title&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;omniture&#34;:null,&#34;description&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;path&#34;:&#34;/wp-content/uploads/auto-shows/frankfurt/2017/2019-porsche-cayenne/02-2019-porsche-cayenne-turbo-NP.jpg&#34;,&#34;thumbnail&#34;:&#34;/wp-content/uploads/auto-shows/frankfurt/2017/2019-porsche-cayenne/02-2019-porsche-cayenne-turbo-NP.jpg?w=320&h=240&crop=1&#34;},{&#34;title&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;omniture&#34;:null,&#34;description&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;path&#34;:&#34;/wp-content/uploads/make/porsche/cayenne/2019/oem/21-2019-porsche-cayenne.jpg&#34;,&#34;thumbnail&#34;:&#34;/wp-content/uploads/make/porsche/cayenne/2019/oem/21-2019-porsche-cayenne.jpg?w=320&h=240&crop=1&#34;},{&#34;title&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;omniture&#34;:null,&#34;description&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;path&#34;:&#34;/wp-content/uploads/make/porsche/cayenne/2019/oem/23-2019-porsche-cayenne.jpg&#34;,&#34;thumbnail&#34;:&#34;/wp-content/uploads/make/porsche/cayenne/2019/oem/23-2019-porsche-cayenne.jpg?w=320&h=240&crop=1&#34;},{&#34;title&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;omniture&#34;:null,&#34;description&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;path&#34;:&#34;/wp-content/uploads/make/porsche/cayenne/2019/oem/30-2019-porsche-cayenne.jpg&#34;,&#34;thumbnail&#34;:&#34;/wp-content/uploads/make/porsche/cayenne/2019/oem/30-2019-porsche-cayenne.jpg?w=320&h=240&crop=1&#34;}]}"></div>
```

I want to match all the occurrences that appear between `;/wp-content/uploads/` and `.jpg`

I tried to match this, but it shows last group only.

I am new to regex, so please correct me with the implementation here, thank you.

Comment: Maybe `;\/wp-content\/uploads\/(.*?)\.jpg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of lookarounds to do clean extractions:

```
(?<=;\/wp-content\/uploads\/)(.*?)(?=\.jpg)
```

https://regex101.com/r/vzJ0FU/1

Comment: This regex worked for me, thanks @MonkeyZeus for quick help.